# JPA - Cascade issue

Tags: java, jpa

I'm currently stuck in the following situation:

When my JSF - JPA project boots up for the first time, it auto creates an admin user and gives it the userType admin:

```
 User user = new User();
                UserType userType = new UserType();
                user.setUsername("admin");
                user.setPassword("admin");
                userType.setName("admin");
                user.setUserType(userType);
                create(user);
                return user;
```

So that code creates a user and a usertype in the database.

However, when I want to assign a userType to a user during the executing of my project, I get a 'Transaction Aborted' error with the following Stacktrace

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception:     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry     'admin' for key 'NAME'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO USERTYPE (NAME) VALUES (?)
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(domein.UserType@1751967)
```

Code looks like this

```
@JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    protected UserType userType;
```

If already tried all of the other different CascadeTypes but none of them supported both the things that I want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
>   'admin' for key 'NAME' Error Code: 1062

from this message, I am guessing you have already a  record in your UserType table with Name=admin ?

The cascading works fine, since we have seen the `insert into usertype` statement.

Interesting is why user->usertype is one2one.. usually it would be @ManyToOne. well it would have something to do with your requirement, maybe your application needs it to be one2one. just feel strange.